# Why javascript return Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

Why javascript throws `Uncaught ReferenceError` when trying to get global variable directly for example `someVar`, but when trying get it through `window.someVar` it gots `undefined`

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError` is raised when you try to access nonexistent variable. When you try to reach for nonexistent **property** you get undefined because it was not defined upon the object. This information is googleable and explained well on MDN. I suggest you research such questions before you ask here, you'll get results quicker and possibly no downvotes..

Answer (score 0):

Please post an example of your code. Global variables should be accessible on the window object for example:

```
var someValue = "foo";
function alertsomeValue(){
    alert(window.someValue);
}
alertsomeValue();
//alerts "foo"
```